# C# - Having trouble dividing by a 0.x number

Tags: c#, .net

My C# program requires two numerical outputs.
A main price will be divided by 20% and 10%.

For example:
Main price = 200
Discounted price: 20% of 200 = 40. Therefore total price is now 160.

I am having issues converting decimals, int's, etc. Here is what I have tried.

```
int discountNumber = 20 / 100;
decimal DiscountedPrice = Convert.ToInt32(TotalPrice)
                          / Convert.ToInt32(discountNumber);
txtTotalPrice.Text = DiscountedPrice.ToString();
```

Comment: You need to make one of your operands decimal - two integers will only return an int (the decimal portion will just be discarded)

Comment: Also check your math.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in  the

```
  int discountNumber = 20 / 100;
```

it's *always* **zero**

Answer (score -1):

change the int to a double. 20/100 will give you a decimal figure not an int

Comment: and 20/100 will still give 0...

Comment: Know the difference between Decimal and Double - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net

Comment: I changed the int to a double and it still gives a 0? How do i get a 0.2 to divide by the total?

Comment: I don't really understand how you're doing it to be honest. You should divide your percentage by 100 then multiply it by the number you wish to find the percentage of... eg: 50% of 20: 50/100 = 0.5 0.5*20= 10

Comment: so for 20% I did 20 / 100 which is 0.2 then the total price divided by that is the discounted price

Comment: yeah you should be multiplying

Comment: 0.2 * discountedprice?